# How to make a function async-signal-safe?

Tags: c++, c, linux, asynchronous, signals

I have the following `sigaction` handler function

```
void signal_term_handler(int sig)
{
    printf("EXIT :TERM signal Received!\n");
    int rc = flock(pid_file, LOCK_UN | LOCK_NB);
    if(rc) {
        char *piderr = "PID file unlock failed!";
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", piderr);
        printf(piderr);
    }
    abort();
}
```

Someone told me that `flock` and `printf` aren't async-signal-safe. And I could not find an alternate async-signal-safe function for  `flock`in this [list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html).

and according to the above link:

> when a signal interrupts an unsafe function and the signal-catching
>   function calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined

Is there a way to make `flock`  async-signal-safe? Or is there another solution to execute `flock` when I receive `TERM` signal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler) for `printf`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979059/use-flock-in-the-sigaction-handler for `flock`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [fcntl()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html) as an alternative to flock().

Comment: Be aware that the semantics of `fcntl()` locks are different from and less useful than those of `flock()`.

Comment: In fact I can use fcntl to develop a new property flock() function as indicated in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988256/how-to-lock-and-unlock-pid-file-with-fcntl). Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 4):

`flock()` is generally async-signal-safe because it is a system call. Its semantics make it hard to implement it differently. It is not in POSIX's list of async-signal-safe functions because it is not in POSIX at all.

You likely do not need the explicit unlock because `flock()` locks are released automatically when all file descriptors referring to the open file description are closed.

The `printf()` and `fprintf()` calls should be replaced with appropriate `write()` calls. The stdio functions are not in the list of async-signal-safe functions and are often strongly async-signal-unsafe.

The `abort()` call is probably best replaced by setting the signal to the default action and resending it to self; this way, shells know that your program exited because of the signal and can abort command sequences when appropriate.

Comment: Can I use `flock()` without problems in the sigaction handler?

Comment: Yes, but as I said you may not need to.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use `exit()` instead of `abort()` in your signal handler, and then put your unsafe functions in an exit handler using [atexit()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit).</strike>

**update:** In general, you should not put any potentially blocking system calls in your signal handler. One way to avoid this is to just set a flag in your signal handler, and then perform the functions you wanted in the context of your main loop.

```
volatile int shutdown = 0;

void signal_term_handler(int sig)
{
    shutdown = 1;
}

void cleanup() {
    printf("EXIT :TERM signal Received!\n");
    int rc = flock(pid_file, LOCK_UN | LOCK_NB);
    if(rc) {
        char *piderr = "PID file unlock failed!";
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", piderr);
        printf(piderr);
    }
}

void *workerFunction(void *arg) {
    while (!shutdown) {
       ... do stuff ...
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //...
    pthread_create(...,workerFunction,...);
    pthread_join(...);
    cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exit-handlers may be called synchronously. Doing so from an asynchronously invoked signal handler make them run how?

Comment: Right, I didn't read the question carefully enough. I guess I was answering a more basic question about how to avoid unsafe functions in a signal handler. In this case, you would want to replace exit() with something like setting a shutdown flag.