# Use flock() in the sigaction handler

Tags: c, linux, signals, flock

`flock()` is generally async-signal-safe because it is a system call. Its semantics make it hard to implement it differently. It is not in the POSIX's [list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) of async-signal-safe functions because it is not in POSIX at all.

Is it possible to use `flock()` in the sigaction handler without problems?

Comment: The Mac OS X documentation for `flock()` doesn't give any direct help.  There's no reason to suppose `flock()` messes with user-space structures, so there's every reason to think it will be async-signal-safe, but that's not conclusive.  The `fcntl()` function, which is the POSIX locking system call, is async-signal-safe, which supports the view that `flock()` can be implemented so it is async-signal-safe, but that's still not proof.  Maybe you should upgrade to use `fcntl()` instead, and then you'll know you're safe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Cna I use `flock()` to lock and `fcntl()` to unlock?

Comment: Please see my addtional answer to your initial question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16979601/694576

Comment: No: you can't use `fcntl()` to unlock what you locked with `flock()`.

Comment: Finally I get an answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988256/how-to-lock-and-unlock-pid-file-with-fcntl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ***@alk*** answer in the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988256/how-to-lock-and-unlock-pid-file-with-fcntl):

We can develop our property `flock()` function (its name could be `async_flock()`). we copy in this new function the content of the origin `lockf()` code and then we make the following changes in order to get an async-signal-safe function:

- replace `__fcntl` with `fcntl`: necessary to make the code compile
- replace `__set_errno(<errno-define>)` with `errno = <errno-define>`: necessary to make the code compile
- replace the call to `memset()` with appropriate assigments `struct fcntl = {0}`: necessary to have it become async-signal-save.