# How to lock and unlock pid file with "fcntl()"

Tags: c, linux, fcntl

I make a reseach on the net and even on the stackoverflow inorder to find an example of using `fcntl()` to lock and unlock pid file `"/var/run/myapp.pid"` but I did not find a clear example for that.

Could you point me to an example using `fcntl()` to lock and unlock pid file?

The lock should not be blocked (if the file is alredy locked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you tagged Linux, verbatim form `man lockf` (emphasis by me):

> On Linux, **lockf**() *is just an interface on top of **fcntl**(2) locking*.  Many other systems implement **lockf**() in this way, but note that POSIX.1-2001 leaves the relationship between **lockf**() and **fcntl**(2) locks unspecified.  A portable application should probably avoid mixing calls to these interfaces.

So looking up the current glibc sources (`eglibc-2.11.3/io/lockf.c`) a possible usage of `fcntl()` to implement locking looks like this:

```
/* Copyright (C) 1994,1996,1997,1998,2000,2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, write to the Free
   Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA
   02111-1307 USA.  */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

/* lockf is a simplified interface to fcntl's locking facilities.  */

int
lockf (int fd, int cmd, off_t len)
{
  struct flock fl;

  memset ((char *) &fl, '\0', sizeof (fl));

  /* lockf is always relative to the current file position.  */
  fl.l_whence = SEEK_CUR;
  fl.l_start = 0;
  fl.l_len = len;

  switch (cmd)
    {
    case F_TEST:
      /* Test the lock: return 0 if FD is unlocked or locked by this process;
         return -1, set errno to EACCES, if another process holds the lock.  */
      fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;
      if (__fcntl (fd, F_GETLK, &fl) < 0)
        return -1;
      if (fl.l_type == F_UNLCK || fl.l_pid == __getpid ())
        return 0;
      __set_errno (EACCES);
      return -1;

    case F_ULOCK:
      fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
      cmd = F_SETLK;
      break;
    case F_LOCK:
      fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
      cmd = F_SETLKW;
      break;
    case F_TLOCK:
      fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
      cmd = F_SETLK;
      break;

    default:
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return -1;
    }

  /* lockf() is a cancellation point but so is fcntl() if F_SETLKW is
     used.  Therefore we don't have to care about cancellation here,
     the fcntl() function will take care of it.  */
  return __fcntl (fd, cmd, &fl);
}
```

A few mods are necessary to firstly make this compile:

- replace `__fcntl` with `fcntl`
- replace `__set_errno(<errno-define>)` with `errno = <errno-define>`

.. and secondly to have it become async-signal-save:

- replace the call to `memset()` with appropriate assigments to the `struct fcntl` variable.

Comment: So If I develop my own `lockf()` function, for example its name will be `async_lockf()`. And then I copy in this function the content of the above function and I make the changes you specified. then the new function `async_lockf()` will be a async-signal-save function and then I can use it in the sigaction handler. is it true ?

Comment: for the `memset()`: I will change it to: `struct flock fl = {0}`

Comment: @MOHAMED: It seems so, yes. But I'd rather refrain from calling it something like `*lockf*` as it does not really refer to `lockf()` but just mimiks it's behaviour. However: You are aware that this is code is GPLed, aren't you?

Comment: No problem for the GPL. I m developing an open source project (GPL) too. and the copyright will be kept

Comment: So finally we come with a solution for the unlock file with a sync-signal-save inorder to use it in the sigaction handler. Thank you very much for your support. this could be the final answer of my first question

Comment: @MOHAMED: As a final note: Use this for locking **and** unlocking. Do not mix it up with calls to `flock()`.

Comment: To let the following generations of readers understand to which "first question" *MOHAMED* is referring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967365/how-to-make-a-function-async-signal-save

Comment: yes indeed. thank you very much for the remark. I added this answer to this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979059/use-flock-in-the-sigaction-handler) too

Comment: in `case F_TEST:`, `fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;` should be `fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;` right? otherwise it will detect read locks only. exclusive lock, `F_WRLCK`, will match/conflict with both types of locks.